# use reflux create a common component,the last component's data replace all

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Dears,
   A problem has troubled me for a week,I need you help.I used React and Reflux to build a common component,I use props set each component different value,but actually it didn't work,the last component's props value will replace all components above.

project have 5 files:

1. Actions.js
2. Store.js
3. component.js
4. test.js
5. test.html

Actions.js,Store.js,component.js,test.js will package to test.min.js

---

*Actions.js:*

```
    var Reflux=require('reflux');
    var Actions=Reflux.createActions([
    'initName',
    'addThing'
]);

module.exports=Actions;
```

*Store.js*

```
var Reflux=require('reflux');
var Actions=require('./Actions');
var Store=Reflux.createStore({
    listenables:[Actions],
    Contents:{},
    onInitName:function(name){
        this.Contents.name=name;
        console.log(this.Contents);
        this.trigger(this.Contents);
    },
    onAddThing:function(){}
});

module.exports=Store;
```

*component.js*

```
const React=require('react');
var Reflux=require('reflux');
var Actions=require('./Actions');
var Store=require('./Store');


var Component=React.createClass({
    mixins:[Reflux.connect(Store,'Contents')],
    componentDidMount:function(){
        Actions.initName(this.props.name);
    },
    changeName:function(){
        var name=this.refs.name.value;
        console.log(name);
        Actions.initName(name);
    },
    render:function(){
        console.log(typeof Actions);
        console.log(Actions);
        if(this.state.Contents==null){
            console.log('this.state.Contents=null');
            return(<div/>);
        }
        return(
            <div className="component">
                <div className="person">
                    <h1>{this.state.Contents.name}'s ToDo List </h1>
                    <input ref="name" type="text" placeholder="name"/><input type="button" value="change name" onClick={this.changeName}/>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }

});
module.exports=Component;
```

*test.js*

```
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
var Component=require('./component');
var Test = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Component name="Tom"/>
                <Component name="Jody"/>
                <Component name="Faye"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Test />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

*test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Faye's Space</title>
    <style>
        .person{
            border:1px solid palevioletred;
        }
        .component{
            border:1px solid gray;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="test.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

run test.html,the result is below.
[http://www.ifengguo.com/laravelapps/nongge_admin/storage/uploads/admin/resources/4c2ebe62ddf0c631507ef4612fa0c6ca.png][1]

How to make component's data like:

```
Tom's ToDo List
Jody's ToDo List
Faye's ToDo List
```

Comment: It looks like you have an object called `Contents` and a property called `name` and you keep replacing it with the most recent name. Instead you should store the data for each person under a unique key. You don't have an ID so I'll just pretend that each name is unique: `this.Contents[name] = name;` there are other parts of code to adjust but that's your essential problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this inside your store

```
getInitialState : function(){
   return {
      Content: {}
   }
}
```

Then do this inside your onInitName()

```
this.state.Content.name = name;
this.trigger(this.state.Content)
```

Comment: Because the <Component /> will be complicated(it will have more child component),so I use component-store-actions.

Comment: The code snippets i put  should be inside  your store, not inside your component, you only need to connect to the store from your component

Answer (score 0):

Your store should be a singleton. You do not want to have a separate store instance for each component. Use the store in the parent and setup an array of Content with an object for each child component. Add an identifier and method in the props for the children to handle interactions with the store.